How to determine the positive odd integers $a$ such that $\forall b\in\{2,4,6,8\}$, $a^6+b$ is not prime?
Consider the equation $a^6+b=q$, where $a$ are certain positive odd integers and $b\in\{0,2,4,6,8\}$. How to determine such positive odd integers $a$ such that $q$ is never prime for any $b\in\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ (or equivalently: for any $b\in\{2,4,6,8\}$)?
For instance $a=29$,  $29^6+2=3\cdot198274441$, $29^6+4=5\cdot118964665$, $29^6+6=7\cdot84974761$, $29^6+8=3\cdot198274443$?
There are other $a$ also, like,
$a=55,83$.
My question is, are these $a$ finitely or infinitely many, and how to go for determining such $a$?

What does "$a$ are certain positive odd integers" mean?  $a$ is a single integer.  What does include "all the even digits" mean?  Do you mean $b$ ranges over ${0,2,4,6,8}$?  over ${2,4,6,8}$?  Over all integers such that every digit in the decimal representation is even (e.g., including numbers like 286)?  What is the context or motivation behind this question?  What are your thoughts and what progress have you made?

I'm able to provide $3$ odd integers as example which exhibits this property.

Sorry, but that doesn't address the feedback that I've provided.  Please [edit] the post to make it clearer what your question is and revise it based on the feedback you've received.

Every integer $a$ of the form $a=210k+1$ (with $k\ge1$) has this property. Specifically:

$a^6$ is obviously not prime;
$a\equiv1\pmod3$, so $a^6+2\equiv1^6+2\equiv0\pmod3$, and so $3\mid(a^6+2)$;
$a\equiv1\pmod5$, so $a^6+4\equiv1^6+4\equiv0\pmod5$, and so $5\mid(a^6+4)$;
$a\equiv1\pmod7$, so $a^6+6\equiv1^6+6\equiv0\pmod7$, and so $7\mid(a^6+6)$;
$a^6+8 = (a^6+2)+6$ and so $3\mid(a^6+8)$ as well.

This construction proves there are infinitely many such integers. In fact, an "upper bound sieve" will show that almost all integers $a$ have this property, in the sense that for any $\varepsilon>0$, the set of integers $a\le x$ without this property has less than $\varepsilon x$ elements as soon as $x$ is sufficiently large in terms of $\varepsilon$.

Thanks for the solution. But I suspect there are other odd integers $a$ which also exhibits this property. Like, $a=45,55,83$ & these are all smaller than $211$.

If you want a more satisfying answer, then you'll probably need to make your question clearer.
